# Filtering data out of Excel file via CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

Is there eny alternative for this than making multiple for loop ?

I have an Excel file :

```
|col1|col2|col3|
 1      x   y   
 2      s   r 
 3     o    o
```

I want an output like this:  When first column argument equals 1, print argument from column 3 from the same row.

```
import csv


reader = csv.reader(open("alerts.csv"), delimiter=',')

rows=[]
for row in reader:
    rows.append(row)
for i in row:
    x"i"?=row[i].split(";")
```

I'm trying to figure out a function that would make another list with split information form `row[i]` but that wont work I feel.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_csv("alerts.csv")
print reader[['col1','col3']].loc[reader['col1'] == 1]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6019417/j-chomel - I will keep this find going forward

Answer (score 0):

So i have difrent idea to sort everything out to diffrent list.

```
import csv


reader = csv.reader(open("alerts.csv"), delimiter=',')

rows=[]
for row in reader:
    rows.append(row)

num_lists=int(len(rows))


lists = []
for p in range(num_lists):
        lists.append([])


for i in rows:
    lists[i][i]=row[i].split(";")

print (lists[0][0])
```

but that seems not work :<